# Android Studio key repeat

Tags: android-studio, ideavim

The latest Android Studio update seems to have changed the key repeat behavior for letters. For example, I cannot hold down i and have the character repeated. Instead, it wants to pop up a suggestion to insert a foreign language character. This is a major hindrance because I use the IdeaVIM keyboard scheme, and need to be able to hold down hjkl characters for moving the cursor more than one character. As it is, I have to tap the key repeatedly. I have looked around to find the preference to disable this character, but am unable to fish it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem. Got fixed after reinstall latest android studio and ideavim without import previous settings. But I think the main reason is OSX, you can disable the pop up by enter this command:

defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false

Ref: http://lifehacker.com/5826055/make-your-keyboard-keys-repeat-properly-when-held-down-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: The defaults command worked for me when I executed it while Android Studio was completely closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to enable it for Android Studio and not globally, use:

```
defaults write com.google.android.studio ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

NB: You need to exit and restart Android Studio to apply the change.

Comment: This gist has a list of commands for other IntelliJ IDEs: https://gist.github.com/lsd/1e1826907ab7e49c536a